# How can I combine steps in Cucumber.js as described in the Ruby Cucumber documentation?

Tags: javascript, ruby, cucumber, cucumberjs

Here: https://relishapp.com/cucumber/cucumber/docs/defining-steps/nested-steps#use-#steps-to-call-several-steps-at-once

I don't have a code sample for what I mean except to say that I'd like to combine and execute multiple steps in aggregate within a single step (think: code reuse). I have no clue of how to accomplish this using Cucumber.js; the documentation is a bit sketchy. :-\

Answer (score 3):

In short you can't, and most likely wont ever be able to do this directly in cucumber-js.

Matt Wynne and Aslak Hellesoy seem to have regrets about ever implementing this concept in cucumber-ruby and suggest using helper methods instead.

> aslakhellesoy commented on Oct 16, 2012
>
> Calling steps from stepdefs is one of those features I wish I never added to Cucumber(-Ruby), because it provides so much rope for people to hang themselves with. It came to be because Ruby stepdefs use anonymous closures that you can't call from elsewhere (unless you go through hoops).
>
> With JavaScript it's a different situation; Step Definitions use first class functions!

---

> mattwynne commented on Aug 27, 2014
>
> I suggest you use helper methods on your World to achieve this kind of reuse. We implemented this feature (we call it "nested steps") in the Ruby Cucumber, and it's been hard to maintain, and led to some very complex dependencies in people's test code.

Apparently Julien Biezemans agrees

> jbpros commented on Aug 13, 2014
>
> Thanks @cono for the PR. However, as has been discussed before this will not be implemented in Cucumber.js.

More on the subject:

- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/11
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/237
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/issues/473
- https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/pull/223

Comment: Thanks! I have been searching for ages on how to do this, but I guess it's time to give up.

It would have been nice to group some common assertions together simply by creating an aggregate statement in the feature file... Ahh well